# Escaping single quote and save to database with quote

Tags: php, mysql

How do I escape single quote for example.

User enters in the name field: **El'art Devoun**

```
$myvar = $data['name']; //name is El'art Devoun
// some code to remove the single quote
```

Then save it to database with data not escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PDO and parameterized queries for you database insert.  This will automatically prevent sql injection etc from the quote (and other non-safe entities):

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO yourTable (name) VALUES (:name)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);

// insert row
$name = $data['name'];
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

more can be found in [the php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

use `addslashes()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

https://php.net/addslashes

https://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: This does not work for me. I've tried both. These still convert single quotation mark to TWO single quotation marks.