# pg_escape_string and single quote - better way than str_replace?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am inputting html form data to postgre via a php script. I do the following processing on every input string taken from the POST data:

```
  function sanitizeString($var, $con)
  {
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    return pg_escape_string($con, $var);
  }
```

Whenever there is a single quote in my input, it is converted to two single quotes. I thought this might be due to the stripslashes() in the sanitizeString() function, but I have the problem even when I comment out that line of sanitizeString (function comes from O'Reilly book on dynamic websites, can't remember author, and yes I know people hate this function).

I saw some people recommend using a PDO object to avoid this single-quote problem ([Escaping single quote and save to database with quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110007/escaping-single-quote-and-save-to-database-with-quote)), but I am using the pg_ specific functions to do parameterized queries and don't want to change everything now to PDO.

I have 3 related questions going from most specific to least specific:

(1) How can I store and display the strings with only a single quote more elegantly than just doing a str_replace every time I access strings that might contain a single quote? 

(2) Are there other buggy characters I should be worried about.

(3) What's the best way to save in a database and then later display html form input exactly as it was input? Seems like there is no magic bullet, but if there is a 'best' way I haven't been able to find it with google and would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel and let pg_query_params() or pg_escape_string() handle the input for a safe piece of content in your SQL.

Comment: I would add « do not store HTML formatted content in a database. » you cut yourself from manipulating it further.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have pared down my function to use only pg_escape_string, but I still have double quotes. How do I *not* get double quotes from single quotes?

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
$var = " 'String' " ;
$new = pg_escape_string($var) ;

// outputs "String" 

$new  = str_replace("''", "", $new) ;    // using two single quotes

// outputs String
```

Answer (score -2):

In my PHP application,  whenever there was a single quote in text,  insertion to postgres database failed.  And there were multiple occurances of single quotes in the text as well.   So,  before inserting into database,  I used
`pg_escape_literal($textToBeInserted)` and it resolved my problem.  The single quotes are visible in application, but no errors are thrown by postgres.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Updated as per @NicoHaase comments

Comment: Even if this is a bit safer than using raw strings, you should not use anything else nowadays than prepared statements